# iOS tableView.backgroundView with no cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, tableview

I've checked how to make background with `UITableView` with this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.JPG"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:tableView.frame];
tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

It works fine, but when there is no cell, the background doesn't display because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't call when there is no cell.

Alright, I would like to display background even if there is no cell, so I tried :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.events.count == 0)
    {
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.JPG"]];
        [tempImageView setFrame:tableView.frame];
        //
        tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
    }
    return self.events.count;
}
```

But I don't know if it's the best choice ?

And how can I make different background size with different devices (iPhone4/5/6/6+) ? Just with image.jpg, image@2x.jpg etc ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I approached it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background0"]];
    [self.tableView.backgroundView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    // Adding a table footer will hide the empty row separators

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Nice man, it works, but do you know for the second part of the question ? How can I make different background size with different devices (iPhone4/5/6/6+) ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I believe you can do it from within the asset catalog, and it will select the specific image for the device.  I'm sure there's an answer on SO.